# Restore pathogen git repos

Tags: git, vim, github

I back up my _vimrc file to google drive so I can grab it to use on a new computer when I'm doing a new [gvim](http://www.vim.org/) installation. I use [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) for all my vim plugins, and was zipping the /vimfiles/bundle directory to upload to google drive too, but this seemed silly when all of the plugins are on github. I would like to have a way to restore all of the pathogen git plugin repositories.

Is there any way to have some kind of "package file" so that I could just do like a git restore for all repos that are in the vimfiles/bundle directory? Or is there another good practice for saving your vim environment?  I am using Windows 8.1 FYI.

Comment: Imo, it is best to create a git repository for your vim files.  Then, you can add the git repositories of your plugins as submodules in your bundle directory.

Comment: If you just want to move a vimrc file consider using a different plugin manager such and vundle, neobundle, or plug which will automatically grab them from github for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative plugin manager called [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) implements what you are looking for. With this plugin manager the addons are listed in the `.vimrc`, so after copying this file to a new location one only needs to clone [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) itself and everything else can then be installed using a single command.
Please try it and see if it fills your needs.

Another option would be to create a git repository with the contents of your `$HOME/.vim` folder and use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to keep track of your vim plugins. For example, in Linux you could do the following:

```
mkdir ~/.vim
cd ~/.vim
git init
git submodule add https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen.git bundle/vim-pathogen.git
git commit -m "Add vim-pathogen plugin"
```

From this moment onward whenever you wanted your plugins in a new location you could simply clone this git repository using the option `--recursive` and all the plugins would be automatically added.
While googling for this I found out that [Vim Cast #27](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) shows an example implementation of what I am trying to describe.

Comment: I have used Vundle and it was really nice, until I discovered pathogen. I just really like being able to just clone a repo and have the plugin.

Comment: But now you're looking for a secondary "package file" to store the information that Vundle allows you to store directly in `vimrc`? That doesn't seem very coherent ;) Nevertheless, I've updated my answer to refer git submodules as an alternative to Vundle.

Comment: What is use of `git submodules` in this case? I didn't noticed any errors just storing plugins' get repos under .vim git repo. Can such errors appear later?

Comment: When you create and cd to your "/.vim" directory, do you mean you are in the actual /.vim (/vimfiles) directory, which has all the /colors, /autoload, /bundle (for pathogen plugins) etc. directories? Or are you in the pathogen "/bundle" directory with just the plugins? I just thought git might be confused if not in the directory directly containing the submodules.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following way to backup and restore my vim environment:

1. Use Pathogen as plugin manager.
2. Copy `.vimrc` to `.vim` folder.
3. Create git repo in `.vim` and push it to remote storage, for example, [github](https://github.com) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).
4. When in new environment, `git clone <my remote repo>` in home folder and create link to `.vimrc` (though, I tested the way with link in Linux only, and I'm not sure if it will work for Windows) or just copy it to your home folder.
   That's it.

I consider my vim configuration as plain git repo, so after adding new plugin or change `.vimrc`, I use `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push`.

The way to `git clone <repo with plugin>` in `.vim/bundle` works just fine and there should not be problems with main repo.

Comment: So are you putting the other repositories' entire files in your repository then? or can your repo kind of bootstrap the other repos and download them? that would be cool

Comment: No, plugins' repositories just stored in `.vim/bundle` folder and they are downloaded after `git clone`. As @Vitor noted, you can use `Vundle` and it will download latest versions of your plugins.